# Can I return to the nexus to use my souls before fighting the boss?

Tags: demons-souls

In Demon Souls, in order to level up, I need to return to the Nexus. Can I return to the Nexus through the Archstone, in order to level up *before* fighting the boss?

Comment: If you're adding additional characters to hit a limit, changes are very good you should be fleshing your question out much more.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious and clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Then you should have no trouble not needing extra characters to bypass the minimum limit.

Comment: @Henk What Frank is trying to say is: it would be a better question if you put an example in the body of the question. For example, the body of your question should be "Can I use the archstone to spend my souls before fighting boss X, the reason this is important is Y and I can't figure out how to do it because Z"

Comment: Adding more information about which boss can also help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return to the Nexus with all your souls unless you use the Archstone. There are multiple Archstones [scattered throughout the world](https://demonssouls.fandom.com/wiki/Archstones), so as long as you have access to one of them, you can return to level up.

There are also items called [shard of Archstone](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/shard-of-archstone) which allow you to return to the Nexus from wherever you might be, without losing your souls.

So, to answer your question, if you can access an Archstone before the boss; yes, you can return to the Nexus before the boss fight.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, yes. But you would usually have to go all the way back to the last archstone. And if you then transport from the Nexus to continue, all normal enemies will have respawned.